# Where are HTTP Status Codes first available in the IIS Pipeline ?

Tags: iis, http-status-codes

Does anyone have any information on where the HTTP Status Codes (200, 404, 500, etc) are first available in the IIS Pipeline?  I'm trying to write a series of http modules and handlers for error handling purposes and I don't particularly want to duplicate requests/responses to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at any of the events here, and take your pick :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693685(v=vs.90).aspx

Theoretically, the status code can be changed by any of the http modules in the pipeline; it just depends on which events they are subscribed to.

For example, an authorization module may subscribe to the `OnAuthorizeRequest` method, and perform its logic at that time, and change the status code if needed.  In another case, a classic ASP app may run as a handler, and you won't be able to determine if the status code is 500 until `OnPostExecuteRequestHandler`.  Finally, an error in a logging module may generate a 500, which doesn't occur until the request processing is nearly finished (`OnLogRequest`)

Further complicating matters, some handlers may spit out unbuffered data during execution, so it could be in any of the `OnSendResponse` events, which don't come in any particular order, and the status code could have changed between responses.

So, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve in order to approach this effectively.  If you could provide more detail, perhaps we could formulate a solution.